# d3 javascript alternate colors on click

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm just starting playing around with d3, and was wondering how you could alternate the colors of a element upon clicking it.

This fiddle changes the color of the circle clicking it, but then I'd like to get the color back to being white after clicking again.

Current Code:

```
var sampleSVG = d3.select("#viz")
        .append("svg")
        .attr("width", 100)
        .attr("height", 100);    

    sampleSVG.append("circle")
        .style("stroke", "gray")
        .style("fill", "white")
        .attr("r", 40)
        .attr("cx", 50)
        .attr("cy", 50)
        .on("click", function(){d3.select(this).style("fill", "magenta");});
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Make yourself a toggle function and pass it into the click: http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/Bvmgm/6/

```
var toggleColor = (function(){
   var currentColor = "white";

    return function(){
        currentColor = currentColor == "white" ? "magenta" : "white";
        d3.select(this).style("fill", currentColor);
    }
})();
```

Comment: @user1443118 I just made an example with no libraries at all :-P http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/WMUQA/

Answer (score 3):

This also worked, albeit in a jankier fashion. . .

```
var PointColors = ['white', 'magenta']
var sampleSVG = d3.select("#viz")
    .append("svg")
    .attr("width", 100)
    .attr("height", 100);    

sampleSVG.append("circle")
    .style("stroke", "gray")
    .style("fill", "white")
    .attr("r", 40)
    .attr("cx", 50)
    .attr("cy", 50)
    .on("click", function(){
        PointColors = [PointColors[1], PointColors[0]]
        d3.select(this).style("fill", PointColors[0]);});
```

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: Does not work in Chrome, works in FF. The problem is in the fill atributte:

```
this.style.fill
```

Chrome change "white" by "#FFFFFF".

By the way, the clearer solution should be toggling the class.

```
.on("click", function(){var nextColor = this.style.fill == "white" ? "magenta" : "white";
        d3.select(this).style("fill", nextColor);});
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/kUZuW/

Comment: Interesting, works on FireFox, but not on Chrome.
Actually, in Chrome, this.style.fill returns #ffffff while in FF returns "white"

Comment: Hehe I just made a mockup with no libraries at all: http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/WMUQA/ :-P