# In D3, how can I switch color of a square between gray and its initial color?

Tags: svg, d3.js

I am learning d3 and am writing a visualization that requires shapes to be toggled between their initial color and gray. This other example does not quite do what I need ([d3 javascript alternate colors on click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10939082/d3-javascript-alternate-colors-on-click)) because I want the two colors to be "initial" and "gray" rather than two hard-coded colors.

I happily noticed that my rectangles have two associated colors that look like original and current:

My attempt below lets you click the shapes to gray, but they don't click back to their initial colors. Could you please advise me on what I'm doing wrong? I'm open to completely revised approaches too.

Thanks!

```
        var w = 300;
        var h = 200;

        var colors = ["Red","Green","Blue"];

        var svg = d3.select("body")
            .append("svg")
            .attr("width", w)
            .attr("height",h);

        var squares = svg.selectAll("rect")
           .data(colors)
           .enter()
           .append("rect")
           .on("click", function(){
                if(d3.select(this).style("fill") !=  "Gray"){
                    d3.select(this).style("fill", "Gray")
                }
                else{
                    d3.select(this).style("fill", d3.select(this).fill)
                };
            });

        squares.attr("x", function(d, i){
                return 100+i*80;
                })
           .attr("y", 100)
           .attr("width", 40)
           .attr("height", 40)
           .attr("fill", function(d){
                return d;
            });;
```

Answer (score 4):

The approach you're taking reads the current value of the `fill` style property of the object to decide how to react to the click. One could say you're "storing truth in the DOM", which is not ideal. Case in point, if you `console.log(d3.select(this).style("fill"))` where you expect it to be `"Gray"` you'll most likely get `#808080`.

Instead, you could store the state of the rect on its datum. From within the click handler, the datum can be gotten using `d3.select(this).datum()`. Then you can say:

```
var clicked = d3.select(this);
var datum = clicked.datum();
if(!datum.isToggled) { datum.isToggled = true; }
else { datum.isToggled = false; }
```

This way, you'd be storing the state (toggled or not) on the datum bound to that object. At this point, you can set the color of `clicked` as you wish, based on `datum.isToggled` being true of false. In your case:

```
if(datum.isToggled) { clicked.style("fill", "Gray"); }
else { clicked.style("fill", datum); }
```

In your code, where you're setting the fill, you have a bug, because you're setting fill to be `d3.select(this).fill` which is undefined. In your case, the fill you want is the value assigned to `datum` because you're binding dom the nodes to the array of strings.

Incidentally, note that since you bound to an array of strings, `datum.isToggled` ends up resolving to `"Red".isToggled`, which surprisingly works in JS, but is weird looking and kind of unexpected. To get around it, you'd want to bind to an array of objects, like:

```
[
  { fill: "Red" },
  { fill: "Green" },
  { fill: "Blue" }
]
```

Then, when you want to apply the fill, you use `datum.fill` or

```
.attr("fill", function(d){
  return d.fill;
});
```

Finally, notice how in one place you use `.attr("fill", ...)` and in another `.style("fill", ...)`? That's risky, because one takes precedence over the other. Instead, use just one of those two consistently.

#### Additional clarification:

The datum I refer to above is the thing that gets bound to the DOM element as a result of calling `.data(...)` on a d3 selection. In your case, you're calling `data(colors)` with an array of strings, so each of the 3 resulting DOM elements will end up having a datum that is one of those 3 strings (`"Red"`, `"Green"` or `"Blue"`). In your code, as you have it currently, if the Red DOM element is clicked, from inside the click handler, running `d3.select(this).datum()` will return the string `"Red"`. That's what it means in d3 for a DOM element to be associated with (or bound to) a datum.

One of my recommendation was to bind to an array of generic JavaScript Objects, instead of an array of string. You can think of each of those objects as a container for properties. In your case each object will only have 1 property, `fill`. So, if you do this, calling `clicked.datum()` will return the javascript object `{ fill: "Red" }` (or Green or Blue).

`isToggled` is not built in or at all related to d3 (you could call it `foo` if you wanted). It would just be a property that you'd set on datum. Like a marker. I.e. on the "Red" datum from the last paragraph, running `datum.isToggled = true` would yield `{ fill: "Red", isToggled: true }`. The next time the DOM element associated with this red color is clicked, `.datum()` would return that very same object, with an `isToggled` set to `true`. That's what I mean by having the datum represent the state of the DOM element. Your code can then decide to set `isToggled` to `false`, yielding `{ fill: "Red", isToggled: false }` and then set the DOM element's color accordingly.

I was also pointing out that since your code currently uses an array of Strings –– not an Array of `{}` –– and if you keep it that way, one might expect that assigning `isToggled` as a property of any of those strings wouldn't work. But in fact this would work, due to the idiosyncrasies of JavaScript. But I think it's too much to explain here...

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Indeed, using console.log I can see that the gray color is actually stored as: "rgb(255, 0, 0)". I can just use this, and make my crufty code work. I'd like to understand your comments though and make my code better-- how do I store the state of the rectangle on the datum? Is the "state" the color or its truth value. Is "isToggled" built into d3, or something I need to write?

Comment: Thank you so much. The Stackoverflow community is such a resource for learners. You are so nice to respond so quickly.

Comment: I incorporated all your advice, and I got it! Thanks again!