# d3.js Alternate colors on click and change back to original on click of another dot

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am working with a scatterplot in d3 and each dot on the graph represents a paper.

All dots are blue on the graph but on click I want that selected paper to change color eg (yellow). But when another dot is clicked I want that first dot to go back to blue and the newly selected dot to turn yellow. How would I achieve this? I have a function called clickHandler which is called when the circles are created at the on click attribute.

Here is a similar question [d3 javascript alternate colors on click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10939082/d3-javascript-alternate-colors-on-click)

But instead of the circle turning back to the original color on the second click of that circle I want it to turn back on a click of another circle.

The following code is from the question linked above, I was wondering would I be on the right track thinking this is the method I should be following for what I want?:

```
function clickHandler (d, i) {

var toggleColor = (function() {

        var currentColor = "blue";
            return function() {
                currentColor = currentColor == "blue" ? "yellow" : "blue";
                d3.select(this).style("fill", currentColor)
                                .style("stroke", "black");
            }
    })
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

This can be as simple as:

```
function clickHandler (d, i) {
  // reset all circle to blue
  d3.selectAll('circle') //<-- or slap a class name on your circles and use that
    .style('fill', 'blue');

  // set selected one to yellow
  d3.select(this)
    .style('fill', 'yellow');
}
```